# Modifying query string before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to modify the URL query string before submitting the form. I'm having a form like below:

```
 <form name="sampleForm" id="sampleForm" method="get" action="/detailVal" style="display:inline">
            <input type="hidden" name="cId" value="${lId}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="sId" value="${sId}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="pKey" value="${pKey}"/>

    onclick="return resetPage('sampleForm',)"><img height="40" width="30" src="/img/next123.png"/></a>

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function resetPage(formName) {
         var thisForm = doc
       }    
    </script>
```

Before submitting the form I want to change the URL from `/detailVal?cId=1&sId=2&pKey=3`
to `/detailVal/cId/1/sId=2/pKey/`

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: onsubmit call a function, inside that you can change the action attribute of the form element.

Comment: tried overriding the submit not worked

Comment: $("#sampleForm").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var querystring = rewrite_interval_qstring();
        // querystring equals "?price=100000,200000" -> exactly what I want !
  querystring = querystring.replace(/[\&amp;?=]/g, '/');
  alert("querystring "+querystring);
        window.location.href = querystring; 
    });

Comment: @Nish : action attribute will not get query string

Comment: When submitting the form you want to go to different url right? On submit, Can't you set the form action url to what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any logic to how the url is built, so just passing the string with the values inserted from the elements is probably what you're trying to do, then just prevent the form from submitting and redirect to that url :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resetPage(formName) {
         var thisForm = doc
       }    

    $(function() {
        $('#sampleForm').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var cId = $('[name="cId"]').val(),
                sId = $('[name="sId"]').val();

            window.location.href = '/detailval/cid/'+cid+'/sid='+sId+'/pKey/';
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [onsubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp) function.