# How to save user input and refresh page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function in JS that's basically a form but in a table (1 row, 3 columns). The first cell is an input box, the second two are buttons. I want that once the user enters text (say a country), and clicks "submit", I want to save the value he entered in a variable, so that once he clicks "refresh", the page will be refreshed with the country in mind. How do I write the functions that saves the value and refreshes the page? Here's the code I have (some of the code is from another answer):

```
function createTable(){

    var body = document.body, tbl  = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width='100%';
    tbl.style.border = "0px solid black";
    tbl.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    tbl.setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px;position:absolute;top:0px;right:00px;");

    for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                if (j == 2) {
                    var td = tr.insertCell();
                    input=document.createElement("input");
                    input.type="option";
                    input.value="Enter Country";
                    td.appendChild(input)

                } else if (j == 1) {
                    var td = tr.insertCell();
                    btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
                    btn.setAttribute("type", "button")

                    var t=document.createTextNode("Submit");

                    btn.appendChild(t);
                    td.appendChild(btn);

                } else if (j == 0) {

                var td = tr.insertCell();
                var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
                var t=document.createTextNode("Refresh");
                btn.appendChild(t);
                td.appendChild(btn)         
                }
        }
    }

    body.appendChild(tbl);
}


createTable();
```

Comment: Is there any reason you’re not doing any of this server-side?

Comment: I would use query strings

Comment: @Jazen For now I'm doing everything locally, and afterwards it will be server sided

Comment: @Dan Can you please explain how? Thanks.

Comment: These questions pertain to query strings in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087634/how-to-change-the-querystring-when-i-submit-my-get-form-using-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697431/modifying-query-string-before-submitting-the-form If you want to do so using something else like php then just google that

Comment: You can save the country as a cookie.

Comment: @user3651766 My name is ‘Jezen’. With regards to your question: I think it’s too broad to fit the SO format. You’re either withholding information about what it is you’re trying to achieve, or you’re not understanding why you’re picking the wrong tool for the job. If you *really* need to save data client-side, read up on [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`localStorage`](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html):

Check if value exists:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("country"))
    // value exists
else
    // value does not exist
```

Set new value

```
localStorage.setItem("country", insert_name_here);
```

Get old value:

```
localStorage.getItem("country");
```